# Make animated parallax header clickable when pressing on image in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to extend a [react-native library](https://github.com/kyaroru/RNParallax) for a parallax header which is really nice, by adding a clickable ability to the parallax background.

Attempted a few ways I've found but none seemed to work.

Things tested:

- TouchableOpacity within Animated.View with onPress event
- TouchableOpacity wrapping the Animated.Image with onPress event
- Created an AnimatedTouchable with the onPress event

Nothing is triggering the passed event, animation works, though.

This is the entire [component code](https://pastebin.com/p4NQC35w) for the ParallaxHeader that I'm using.

As you may see, I added the TouchableOpacity into this method:

```
  renderHeaderBackground() {
    const { backgroundImage, backgroundColor, onBackgroundPress } = this.props;

    const currStyles =
    [
      styles.header,
      {
        height: this.getHeaderHeight(),
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      },
    ];

    return (
      <Animated.View style={currStyles}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBackgroundPress}>
            {backgroundImage && this.renderBackgroundImage()}
            {!backgroundImage && this.renderPlainBackground()}
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
```

As in the other ones too related to Header, but none worked. Any idea? I thought it could be due to the position: 'absolute' property of the header style, but it wasn't, I tested removing it.

Comment: can you show your `onBackgroundPress`?

Comment: After like 3 more hours i was able to solve it with the help of the library creator :) thanks for trying to help tho!